# Angular: AWSAppSyncClient is not compatible with ApolloClient

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo-client, aws-appsync

I am trying to use Apollo to connect to AWSAppSync(Graphql) for my Angular project.

what I've done:

```
import AWSAppSyncClient from 'aws-appsync';
import { AUTH_TYPE } from 'aws-appsync/lib/link/auth-link';
import {Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';

export class GraphqlService {

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {
  }

  hydrated() {
    const appsyncClient = new AWSAppSyncClient({
      url: appSyncConfig.graphqlEndpoint,
      region: appSyncConfig.region,
      auth: {
        type: AUTH_TYPE.API_KEY,
        apiKey: appSyncConfig.apiKey,
      }
    });
    this.apollo.setClient(appsyncClient);
    return appsyncClient.hydrated();
  }

}
```

I got a fail compilation.

> Argument of type'AWSAppSyncClient' is not
>   assignable to parameter of type 'ApolloClient'.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

To get past the type error, you have to wait for the client to hydrate and return the variable after the promise resolves.

```
this.appsyncClient.hydrated().then(
  client => {
    this.apollo.setClient(client);
  }
)
```